# Practice Pedal missing hardware

Tags: piano, repair

I have a Winter 1968 spinet that is missing the practice pedal dampening bar, hardware brackets and spring...Any ideas on finding parts?Thanks
Joe

Comment: I have two spare strings for my electric guitar.  Trade you.

Answer (score 1):

The Winter piano company is now defunct, but the good news is that most manufacturers didn't design their own unique parts for this type of function, but bought them from other manufacturers.

The bad news is that since you apparently don't have the original parts (even if they were broken) you don't know exactly the replacement parts look like. Also the "best" suppliers of parts only deal with professionals, not with the general public - it's just too much effort for them to do otherwise, for individuals with small one-off requests (like yours.)

For example here is a supplier who does deal with the public, but they do *not* offer any advice or consultation service - so you are on your own to figure out what parts you need (assuming this is the right web page for your problem, of course). http://www.stevespianoservice.com/Online-Piano-Parts-Catalog/piano-pedal-hardware.htm

So your best bet is to find a piano technician who can get the required parts and do the repair. It's probably not going to be a big and expensive job.